# Convert an XML file to CSV file in Fsharp

Tags: .net, xml, csv, f#, type-providers

I am playing with Fsharp script and trying to find a way to convert data from an XML file to a CSV file.

I started by reading the XML file with typeprovider, what I wanted after that is to use ServiceStack.Text serializer but of course the data are not ready for it as I still have an XmlProvider.

I am probably appraoching the problem from the wrong side. Any insight ?

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to use XML and CSV type providers, you could define two types - one to represent your input based on a sample and one to represent your output based on an explicit schema.

Assuming `test.xml` looks like this:

```
<data>
  <item foo="1" bar="2" />
  <item foo="1" bar="3" />
</data>
```

You can then define the types as below. For the `Output` type, we're saying what are the column names and their types for the output CSV:

```
open FSharp.Data

type Input = XmlProvider<"c:/temp/test.xml">
type Output = CsvProvider<"foo (int), bar (int)">
```

Now you can turn the input data into output rows, add them to a new empty CSV file and save it to a string using `SaveToString` or to a file using just `Save`:

```
let newRows =
  [ for r in Input.GetSample().Items ->
      Output.Row(r.Foo, r.Bar) ]

Output.GetSample().Append(newRows).SaveToString()
```